# After rebasing dev onto main, dev is the same number of commits ahead and behind

Tags: git, github

I have two branches that will always start with the same commit history: `dev` for new features and `main` for production. When I want to add a new feature, I'll branch off of `dev` and commit all my work to the `feature` branch. When I'm done, I'll use GitHub's "Squash and Merge" (combine the changes into a single commit and do a fast forward merge) to move the changes to dev (or if it's a single comment, I'll use "Rebase and Merge"). Then when it's time to do a release, I'll "Rebase and Merge" (fast-forward merge without combining the commits) the `dev` changes into `main`.

To my understanding, the commit histories of those branches should still be the same, but instead, the `dev` branch is exactly the same number of commits ahead and behind `main`. I resolve that by checking out `dev` and doing `git rebase origin/main` then `git push --force`.

I know that isn't the best way to do it and I'm wondering: what am I misunderstand about rebasing, squashing, and merging that is causing this to happen? And what is an appropriate way to handle this branching strategy?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer (perhaps too short) is: after using GitHub's <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> button, you should generally just abandon the branch you've just rebase-and-merge-d.  Delete it entirely, for instance, or rename it if you want to save it for a while, for some reason.

In your case, you can then create a new `dev` off `main` if you like, although there's little purpose to doing so.  You might as well just use `main` directly.

The problem here is that even if the commits *on* `dev` *could* be fast-forwarded into `main`, GitHub's <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> button insists on copying them anyway.<sup>1</sup>

When commits have been copied to new-and-improved commits, *everyone* using the old-and-lousy commits must switch to the new-and-improved commits.  If GitHub had done the rebase on your own repository, or made you do it, your Git would have done this automatically.  You could then fast-forward your own `main` and then `git push` your `main` to GitHub's `main` and they would fast-forward their `main`:

```
# locally
git fetch  # so that origin/main is up to date
git checkout dev && git rebase origin/main
git checkout main && git merge --ff-only dev
git push origin main
```

Or, more simply:

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/main
git push origin HEAD:main
```

(you can probably delete your own `main` entirely).

If you like doing all of this through GitHub's web interface, though, you just have to accept that their <kbd>REBASE AND MERGE</kbd> is ... flawed and annoying.

---

<sup>1</sup>When they're coming from some other fork, there's at least some theoretical reason to do that; when they're coming from your own repository, it's just ... *annoying*.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to understand is that neither Rebase And Merge nor Squash And Merge is a  merge. And Rebase And Merge isn't a rebase either. These are pretty terrible names.

Moreover, you can't move or copy a commit. You can only create a new commit.

Rebase And Merge *makes new commits and adds them to the end of the target branch.* It leaves the source branch untouched. No merge. No rebase either; it's sort of a rebase but not really, it's just a series of cherry picks, while rebase is more than that.

Example: If dev has X and Y and you Rebase and Merge, dev still has X and Y plus now master has XX and YY. They are both now 2 ahead and 2 behind one another.

So your strategy *always* results in an equal number of unshared commits at the ends of dev and master.

(Squash and Merge is just the same except that it always adds just *one* new commit to the target branch. So you always end up one behind and n ahead.)