# Understand GitHub branch logic - branch is ahead after rebase

Tags: git, github

We have `dev`, `staging` and `master` branches (`dev` is the default and protected - everything should work over PRs). So when we create new features we create feature branches from `dev`, create a PR and merge that using GitHub's *Squash and merge* option.

Then we want to merge the changes into staging, so we create a PR from `dev` into `staging` and merge that PR normally. This causes an action which uses semantic release to build a new beta version, do some stuff and commit these changes. So now the staging branch is two commits ahead of `dev` (the merge commit and the generated one).

Now I want to sync back the staging branch into `dev`. When I create a PR for that I use rebase, because I believe it's correct; I just want the two added commits to be in `dev` as well. But after merging this commit the staging branch is not even with `dev`, it says it is 2 commits ahead and one behind.

When I then create a PR from `dev` to `staging` GitHub shows some changes (the changes that were done by the semantic release commit), for example a new version number. But if I manually compare the files in the branch or via my IDE, they are the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When git reports ahead and behind information it does not take into account the *contents* of the commits. It simply asks "Can branch X reach commits that branch Y can't?", if the answer is yes, then those commits are what "X is ahead of Y" means, or "Y is behind X". That's all. Since rebase creates new commits, even though those contains the same content as the original ones, they're technically not on the source branch and thus you get this ahead/behind situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After rebasing dev onto main, dev is the same number of commits ahead and behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68563424/after-rebasing-dev-onto-main-dev-is-the-same-number-of-commits-ahead-and-behind)

Comment: Okay but then what am i supposed to do to make it work like i described? 

Comment: @matt i guess through the linked thread i understand why it's not working, but not what i should do instead

Comment: Have whoever is merging this *not* use the rebase-and-merge mode, and the problem will go away entirely. If you need to use the rebase-and-merge mode for some reason, you'll have to come up with a followup process.